# preserving brackets in mathml

Tags: mathml, sbml

I'm using SBML which is an XML format for capturing numerical simulations. This uses MathML to capture equations that relate the amounts of the different things in the simulation. When I write the equations down by hand, I add some brackets that are not strictly needed, but which make the equations easier to read. For example, I may have an equation that by hand I'd write as:

```
z = (ax + by) + (cx + dy)
```

When this goes into MathML, these brackets are stripped out, and once I pretty-print the MathML, it comes out as:

```
z = ax + by + cx + dy
```

This makes me sad. Is there a way to capture these (redundant) brackets in the MathML expression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't say if you are using presentation or content mathml. I would guess content as it would be rare for you to lose the brackets in presentation rendering.

Content MathML you could mark it up as

```
<apply><sum/>
  <apply><csymbol>bracket</csymbol>
    <apply><sum/>
      <apply><product/><mi>a</mi><mi>x</mi></apply>
      <apply><product/><mi>b</mi><mi>y</mi></apply>
    </apply>
   </apply>
  <apply><csymbol>bracket</csymbol>
    <apply><sum/>
      <apply><product/><mi>c</mi><mi>x</mi></apply>
      <apply><product/><mi>d</mi><mi>y</mi></apply>
    </apply>
   </apply>
</apply>
```

where you give the csymbol bracket a presentation rule of putting a bracket round its argument.